# How to select multiple columns from datatable in linq group by?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable, and i want to grouped with a column .

I use this code for it :

```
DataTable  dtList = list1.Items.GetDataTable();
         var grouped = from row in dtList.AsEnumerable()
                      group row by row["T"] into valueGroup
                      select new { Value = valueGroup.Key, ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]) };
```

My problem is : it is select two column(id,value). I want select multiply column.

How to select other column of dtlist ?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? The other answer does not work, because in order to get those columns you either need to put it in `group by` clause (as I described in my answer) or use an aggregation method (as you did with `ID` in your question). If you have any issues using the method I've described, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select multiple columns to be groupped by, try something like this:

```
DataTable  dtList = list1.Items.GetDataTable();
var grouped = from row in dtList.AsEnumerable()
                      group row by new { T = row["T"], U = row["U"] } into valueGroup
                      select new { Value = valueGroup.Key, ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]) };
```

This will give you multiple columns returned as an anonymous type objects with `T` and `U` properties accessible in the `Value` field of the return set.

I've tested this and it seems to work on a sample data set.

It's based on a solution described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/54f6ac70-e74c-4d9d-a9ee-6373714c0755.

**Edit**

When using `group by` clause all items are divided into groups and for each group only one item is returned, so in order to refer to a column, you have to either put it in the `group by` clause or  use an aggregation method on it (like you did with `ID` field and `Max()` method).

**However, if you want to make the groups, get the maximum `ID` for each group and then retrieve other columns for those items** (with maximum `ID` value in each group) you can use a `join` with the same table. This code shows how to do it in your case for sample `T` and `U` columns. It seems to work correctly on a test data set:

```
var dtListEnumerable = dtList.AsEnumerable();
//group items and get max ID for each group
var groupedTemp = from row in dtListEnumerable
          group row by row["T"] into valueGroup
          select new { Value = valueGroup.Key, ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]) };

//join to get the rest of columns for each item with max ID returned for each group
var grouped = from groupedItem in groupedTemp
          join row in dtListEnumerable on groupedItem.ID equals row["ID"]
              into tablesJoined
          from row in tablesJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new
          {
              ID = groupedItem.ID,
              T = row["T"], 
              U = row["U"]
          };
```

If you need any help with this, let me know. If it does not return data you want to retrieve, please give some more details about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but when i set t,u for group by, it is select all rows of dtlist and don't work group by !

Comment: It's because groupping by all the columns is almost the same as running query without `group by` at all. I try to explain this a little bit in my updated answer. Take a look at it and try the second method described. It may be giving you data you want.

Comment: No problem, thanks for accepting my answer :). One tip: when you find an answer helpful, not only accept it, but also upvote it. This will probably make some people help more willingly.

Answer (score 1):

to select multiple column (column1, column2, colummn3) that are in your dtList:

```
DataTable  dtList = list1.Items.GetDataTable();
var grouped = from row in dtList.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by row["T"] into valueGroup
                  select new {
                         Value = valueGroup.Key,
                         ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]),
                         col1 = row["column1"].ToString(),
                         col2 = row["column2"].ToString(),
                         col3 = row["column3"].ToString()
                          };
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't know row["column1"] in select.I get error (the name 'row' doesn't exit in current context )

Comment: you have to set your column name (column1 was a sample ) you can access using index also (row[2], row[3]...